# Tomcat 7 failed to start Web App and threw java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal type for StackMapType: -89

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have a Web Apps that I built the jar file using JDK 1.7.
I deployed it on Tomcat 7 and it threw this exception at start up.

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal type for StackMapType: -89
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.StackMapType.setType(StackMapType.java:73)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.StackMapType.<init>(StackMapType.java:65)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.StackMapType.<init>(StackMapType.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.StackMapEntry.<init>(StackMapEntry.java:55)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.StackMap.<init>(StackMap.java:73)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:145)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Code.<init>(Code.java:85)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:126)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FieldOrMethod.<init>(FieldOrMethod.java:58)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Method.<init>(Method.java:72)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:268)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2101)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1928)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more
```

I used a trial and error method and found out the jar file that I built for my app causes the issue. I searched Web and some one mentioned it could be related to version of Java compiled code and Java run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the hint from this post ["](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=137183130517812&w=2)http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=137183130517812&w=2

> Christopher Schultz wrote:
>   "I would expect this kind of thing if you used a current BCEL against a
>   newer .class file generated for example by Java 8, which BCEL might
>   not yet support (or at least the version Tomcat uses)."

I checked the POM file and also project properties in Eclipse.

I noticed even though I was using JDK 1.7 but Eclipse was compiling the code for 1.5 because I had forgot to set the correct compile settings at

> Project properties -> Java Compiler-> JDK Compliance

I changed it from 1.5 to 1.7 and built the jar file, everything worked fine. :-)